# Отправка сообщения на почту через функцию mail(), на php

Tags: php, email, openserver

Необходимо реализовать отправку сообщения на почту через php. Что я делаю неверно?

```
$variable = "Какой-то текст.";
$to = $mail;
$subject = 'Тема';
$message = "Текст сообщения: $variable";
$headers = array(
   'From' => 'silischtschew.d@gmail.com',
   'Reply-To' => 'silischtschew.d@gmail.com',
   'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Прикладываю также логи почты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исправил настройки способа отправки почты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы там на вкладке **Почта** заполнили поля? SMTP сервер, пользователь, пароль и пр.?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно настроить вкладку "почта", указать вместо файла SMTP сервер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]